# Get Date of Next Week in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, date

How in VB.net would you take a date say today. And then find the what the date of Monday or Friday of the following week. If today is Thursday and I am searching for the next Friday then I would want tomorrow's date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [DayOfWeek](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dayofweek.aspx) enumeration to find this:

```
Private Function GetNextDate(day As DayOfWeek) As DateTime
    Dim now As DateTime = DateTime.Today
    Dim today As Integer = CInt(now.DayOfWeek)
    Dim find As Integer = CInt(day)

    Dim delta As Integer = find - today
    If delta > 0 Then
        Return now.AddDays(delta)
    Else
        Return now.AddDays(7 - delta)
    End If
End Function
```

Using your example, if you call:

```
Dim date = GetNextDate(DayOfWeek.Friday)
```

You'd get tomorrow's date

Comment: I don't think this is correct.  If delta is not >0, then it should be returning now.AddDays(7 + delta), not 7 - delta.  The delta is negative if it's less than zero so the double negative give you a positive resulting in the date for that day of the week NEXT week, not tomorrow as in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Private Function NextMonday() As String
        Dim Tdate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)
        Do While Tdate.DayOfWeek <> DayOfWeek.Monday
            Tdate = Tdate.AddDays(1)
        Loop
        Return Tdate.ToShortDateString()
    End Function
```

Comment: explain about code you have written for batter understanding of your answes.

Answer (score 0):

The solution proposed by Reed Copsey doesn't work properly.
This is my version:

```
Public Shared Function GetNextDate(day As DayOfWeek) As DateTime
    Dim now As DateTime = DateTime.Today
    Dim today As Integer = CInt(now.DayOfWeek)
    Dim find As Integer = CInt(day)

    Dim delta As Integer = find - today
    If delta >= 0 Then
        Return now.AddDays(delta)
    Else
        Return now.AddDays(7 - (-1 * delta))
    End If
End Function
```

If the day of week as argoument is equal to today then today.